# xamarin forms Properties/Preferences max recommended string length

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

In the docs for properties/xamarin.essentials preferences they mention to not store "large text". I'm wondering what is considered "large text".
I want to know how big of a class is safe/performant to serialize as json.

Comment: I don't think there is any hard limit.  I would probably avoid anything bigger than a few K.

Comment: so in your opinion a 50kb json string is a big no no?

Comment: I would just manually serialize that to a file

Comment: yea i was doing that actually just liked how simple props/prefs are hehe

Comment: noob question.. how can i makr this as answered? i have to "write my own answer"?

Comment: just write an answer to the question in the Answer box

Comment: FWIW I'm having no problems using SecureStorage with 25kb + Json strings on Pixel 3 Android Emulator. Not tried iOS or on device yet as I write this post.

Answer (score 1):

so it seems anything more than a few kb should be written to a file